# Why don't urls to my css and images work in Firefox?

Tags: html, css

With any other browser the website loads fine with the *CSS file* along with the images.

On *firefox* however, the CSS *file* does not seem to load along with the *images*
I have noticed that only one out of the five images has loaded on firefox for some reason. I have also noticed that the background pictures for my div elements have not loaded in, but replaced with black. This could be because I changed my contrast to black/green.

I have seen on another question that I cannot seem to find the link to again that they said that firefox reads backslashes instead of forwardslashes to link files. I have tried this, and still however does not work.

Here is how I load my CSS file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles\main.css">
```

This is how I have a src for an image

```
<img id="toplogo" src="images\toplogo.png">
```

How would I get firefox to load these things? (images/CSS file)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a back-slash ' \ ' instead of a forward-slash ' / '

Comment: "firefox reads backslashes instead of forwardslashes to link files". I have never used backslashes for my filepaths. Though I can't imagine this would cause your problem.

Comment: You can use normal slashes, that should not worry. The code is OK, I believe you encountered cache problems (either firefox has a faulty cache or the resource is actually wrong and the browsers just show something cached from earlier). Try Ctrl+F5 for a cache-refresh

Comment: @Felk Treid Ctrl+F5, still the same.

Comment: @Norman Breau I read from a different question to use normal slashes.

Comment: @JarFile: Backslashes are the *opposite* of normal slashes. (DOS/Windows directory conventions, however common, are not normative here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file paths are incorrect for both the 'href' and 'src'.  Try revising them to the following:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">`

and

`<img id="toplogo" src="images/toplogo.png">`

Comment: You changed nothing from that code, are you telling me that I have href and src wrong, and it is supposed to be for img href and for link src.

Comment: @JarFile - I did change the code. Take a closer look. You have backslashes in both file paths that should be forward slashes.

Comment: If anyone wants to read more on why backslashes aren't allowed in general or for firefox specifically you can read more here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=64488 and also reference "RFC 2396 section 2.4.3" which states "\" is not allowed within URI's.

Comment: Ok, makes sense now didn't look close enough I guess.

Comment: If you do know, the images are now working but for a background image for a div: `background-image: url(images/top.png); height: 204px; width: 101%; border: 1px solid black;` It is not showing the background, but black. Is this because of my black/green contrast, or firefox?

Comment: It's likely that your url path is incorrect.  If you are calling url(images/top.png) from your css file then you are asking it to call the image from an image directory located in the css directory e.g. domain.com/css/images/top.png.  Assuming this is not what you meant you need to reference the correct directory by moving back one level with '../' so that your final url reads: url(../images/top.png).

Comment: I see what you mean by that, everything works like usual in every other browser but firefox. I have noticed that firefox takes on my color contrast of black/green when loading websites. This could be the reason? Also firefox does not load the colored text which I am sure of is the contrast.
I put in `background-image: url(../images/top.png); height: 204px; width: 101%; border: 1px solid black;`